# Knit to PDF gets stuck at auto.arima function

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using RStudio. When I use Knit to PDF option, the process gets stuck at `auto.arima`. When I run the chunk everything is OK. When I press Knit to PDF after removing `auto.arima` command again no problem. It does not matter what data to use as an input to `auto.arima` or in which chunk I put it.

For example the following code will not be converted to PDF:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r cars}
library(forecast)
auto.arima(1:100)
```
````

**Workaround**

I found out that using command line solve the problem:

```
rmarkdown::render("input.Rmd", "pdf_document")
```

Comment: Is there an error message? What does it say? Does you load all relevant packages in your document?

Comment: No error. No warning. Just gets stuck at the chunk with a CPU load of 100 percent.

Comment: I doubt you'll get any answers without a reproducible example. Can you share sample code? Does this happen with any example dataset or is it particular to your data?

Comment: Is the problem particular to `knitr`? If you run `auto.arima` on that same input in a normal R session, does it complete reasonably quickly?

Comment: @GregorThomas It runs fast less than one second.

Comment: @mikeck It does not matter what data I use. Even with `auto.arima(rnorm(100))` it gets stuck.

Comment: Could you show the code in that chunk? Including the chunk options? And perhaps, for good measure, include your R, `knitr`, and `forecast` package versions?

Comment: @GregorThomas As I said it does not matter. Whatever place in any chunk if I put `auto.arima(rnorm(100))` it gets stuck at that chunk.

Answer (score 0):

Works on my computer, maybe reinstall the forecast package, or uninstalla and reinstall R

```
install.packages("forecast", dep = TRUE)
```